# Problema com Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou querendo fazer no meu site, algo parecido com esse modelo:

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_49159/#homePage

Só que estou com problema para posicionar a imagem entre uma div e outra!

Segue meu código:

```
<header class="navbar-wrapper header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Web Design Moderno <br> e Inteligente</h1>
                    <p>Meu nome é Luciano Oliveira. Eu sou um web designer e consultor web. Buscar e encontrar as melhores formas para uma desenvolvimento web criativo, criando sites e sistemas que oferece aos consumidores um exelente desempenho para atingir as metas especificadas.</p>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="header-photo">
                    <figure>
                        <img title="Coder. Designer. Professional." alt="Mark Anderson" src="img/luciano.png">
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Segue o CSS:

```
body { padding-top: 50px; }


.header {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url("img/bg1.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #e6795c;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
.header-photo {
    text-align: center;
}
.header-photo figure {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO.pt, já tentou fazer isso usando `position:absolute;bottom:-<metade_do_tamanho_da_imagem>;`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando `position:absolute;` e posicionando o objeto de acordo com o tamanho.

Para o seu modelo fiz da seguinte forma:

CSS

```
.header-content{
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

.header-photo {
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-110px;
    width:300px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:100px;

}

.header-photo figure {
    background-color: rgba(51, 180, 224, 0.8);
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML

> No HTML apenas adicionei a classe `header-content` no conteúdo do `header` e copiei a `row` do conteúdo para após o `header`.

**[Resultado](http://www.bootply.com/QXGbNLF8Nl)**

Obs.: Note que você tem que levar em conta o tamanho da imagem para posiciona-la corretamente.

PS.: Isso é apenas um esboço rápido, pode-se ter um código bem melhor trabalhando em cima dessas "coordenadas".

Comment: Valeu Kadu!! Vou ver aqui!